# Не получается изменять HingeJoint через скрипт

Tags: c#, unity3d

Делал хоррор на юнити (3д) и хотел добавить туда дверь. Зашёл на документацию по юнити посмотреть как менять параметр *targetPosition* у *HingeJoint* чтобы сделать открывание и закрывание двери. Сделал тестовый скрипт.

```cs
using UnityEngine;

public class Door : MonoBehaviour {
    [SerializeField] private JointSpring spring;

    void Update() {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown("e") || Input.GetKeyDown("joystick button 0")) {
            spring.targetPosition = 179f;
        }
    }
}
```

Суть скрипта в том, чтобы при нажатии клавиши **E** или кнопки **A** на джойстике параметр *targetPosition* у *spring* менялся на *179f*, но в игре это не работает. *targetPosition* у *HingeJoint* остаётся на нуле. Попробовал продебагать скрипт добавив внутрь *if* строчку *Debug.Log("1");* , *if* работает исправно, но *targetPosition* не меняется. Также после компиляции скрипта в консоли появляется предупреждение что параметр *spring* существует, но в коде не используется. [Видео (Гугл диск)](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1zdcD393v9yBcw9yE6wYVXeQanHDBVfob/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"параметр spring существует, но в коде не используется" - это как раз говорит о том, что никакой реакции на изменение этого параметра не последует, так как он не читается, а ему только присваивается значение. Возможно, дело в том, что spring - это частное поле в классе Door. Должно быть как-то не так.

Comment: Спасибо, теперь понял почему оно не работает